# Executing grouped animations in queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a spinner and a table.

When the table is loading, I want to hide the table and show the spinner.
Once the loading is done, I want to hide the spinner, and show the table again.

I have this working, but when the ajax call completes before the animations are finished, I end up with both the spinner showing and the table.

This is my current code

```
setLoading(true);// below is executed
$('#table').fadeOut(200, function(){$('#spinner').fadeIn()}
setLoading(false);/ below is executed
$('#spinner').fadeOut(200, function(){$('#table').fadeIn()}
```

But when the ajax call finishes when the spinner is still fading in, I end up with the both the table, and both the spinner showing.

Is there any way to queue grouped animations?

How I want it to be:

```
Start Table fadeout
End Table fadeout
Start spinner fadein
End spinner fadein
Ajax call Finished
Start spinner fadeout
End spinner fadeout
Start Table fadein
end Table fadein
```

what's happening:

```
Start Table fadeout
Ajax call finishes
Start spinner fadeout
End spinner fadeout
Start Table fadein
End Table fadeout
Start spinner fadein
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events.

In ajaxStart event, you can show the Spinner and hide the table  and in the ajaxStop you can Hide the Spinner and show the table.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( ".spinner" ).hide();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $( ".spinner" ).show();
});
```

Comment: I'm already doing this, but with fadein and fadeout, because of the animations, I have execution order issues

Comment: How much time does the ajax call takes to complete ? May be you have the fade transitions for too long.

Comment: It's under 100 ms. That's why I want a solid solution that queue's the grouped animations

Comment: From UX standpoint, that might not be the best approach, letting the user wait for the transitions when the work has been done. You need to be aware of the `event loop` and how the events are queued in the loop.

Comment: I get what you are saying, the user shouldn't be waiting for previous events to be done, while all the data is already ready. I will look into the event loop